# Materialze Input bottom border-bottom color not changing on focus

Tags: html, css, focus, border, materialize

I have the following html:

```html
        <div class="centered">
          <form class="col">
            <input type="text" class="input-field"></input>
            <span class="helper-text">Email</span>
            <div className="button-wrapper">
              <button className="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

and the following css:

```css
.input-field input[type=text]:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4ec632;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #4ec632;
}
```

The bottom outline of the input when focused is still the default blue-ish color instead of the green #4ec632. I've tried multiple solutions and referred to the materialize documentation, but nothing has seemed to work thus far. Any ideas on what I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your CSS selector to make it change the style when the input field is focused. I have also changed the border and shadow width to 10px to make it shown obvious.

For your info, you might want to change the [outline](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp) instead of the border. Outline only can apply to the whole element and not able to just change the outline bottom.

[image]

```css
/*.input-field input[type=text]:focus {*/
input[type=text].input-field:focus {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #4ec632;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 #4ec632;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
          <form class="col">
            <input type="text" class="input-field"></input>
            <span class="helper-text">Email</span>
            <div className="button-wrapper">
              <button className="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the thorough response, however - the updated css selector and adding a color change to the outline still seems to have no effect. Running that segment alone works, yes, but I guess the goal is to manually override the style that materialize-css already has.

Comment: @konar do you change the outline color with `outline-color: #4ec632;`? It should work with the StackOverflow code snippet. Do you mean it does not work in your code? Have you tried to insert `!important` keyword to override the property value?

Comment: just adding !important to my original CSS worked just fine, thank you! I didn't know that was a thing until now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To control the focus border-color the way that materialize does it:

**1) Use the correct markup**

```
<div class="input-field">
  <input id="first_name2" type="text" class="validate">
  <label class="active" for="first_name2">First Name</label>
</div>
```

This is an input/label pair nested inside div with a class of `.input-field` - the wrapper allows the label to move when focussed. (It is not supposed to be applied to the input itself as in your example). You are also missing a label (which may be deliberate).

**2) Use the correct css override:**

```
input[type=text]:not(.browser-default):focus {
     border-bottom: 1px solid firebrick !important;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 firebrick !important;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 firebrick !important;
   }

 input[type=text]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label {
     color: firebrick;
 }
```

Repalce `firebrick` with your desired colour.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/ExjmXKo).